Captcha solving using Python
I am trying to extract values from below CAPTCHA image but my code is giving me output as none. I am getting empty string as output.

I have tried using below code. While it was working fine with below image.

def read_captcha():
    ptes.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
    try:
        img = cv2.imread('ss.png', 0)
        img = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
        imagetext = ptes.image_to_string(img)
    except TypeError:
        imagetext="a b"
    l = imagetext.split()
    s = ""
    for i in range(len(l)):
        s += l[i]
    if len(s)>0:
        return s
    else:
        return ""`


Why do you think they are using wiggly digits? The purpose of a CAPTCHA is to prevent this sort of automation.

CAPTCHA are deliberately used to prevent OCR tools like Tesseract to read the content and thus crack the CAPTCHA. There are indeed machine learning [wiki] approaches to this, these do not focus on really "understanding" and recognizing characters, it is then more a classification problem that is easier than what Tesseract does, since the alphabet only consists out of digits, the number of digits is fixed and often the digits are located approximately at the same location.
But most websites abandoned CAPTCHAs anyway, since it turns out machine learning eventually outperforms machines with this. The "I am not a robot" checkbox does not check the skills of humans to recognize digits, it looks to the path the mouse makes to reach the checkbox, and tries to determine if a machine did that, or a human, which will usually not take the absolute optimal path, and often has a small amount of noise involved.
